# How do handle dynamically loaded javascript and avoid HTML collision

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been smashing my head against a brick wall for the past 3 hours trying to figure out how to handle this.

**Here's what I am trying to:**

When I press a **viewProduct** button, it loads a page **product/view/{id}** via a simple jQuery ajax call and insert it in a div.

**Here is my main page (index.php)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".viewProduct").on('click', function() {
        var productID = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://mywebappurl.com/product/view/" + productID,
            success: function(view) {
                $("#productInfo").html(view);
            }
        });
});
</script>

<button class="viewProduct" data-id="11">View Product</button>

<div id="productInfo"></div>
```

Product/view contains some HTML (including **viewParentProduct**) and some javascript.

**Here product/view.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // More javascript here....


    $("#viewParentProduct").on('click', function() {
        var parentProductID = 15; // This number changes depending on the product and comes from PHP

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://mywebappurl.com/order/view/" + parentProductID,
            success: function(view) {
                $("#parentProductInfo").html(view);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="viewParentProduct">View parent product</button>

<div id="parentProductInfo"></div>
```

So far, it works fine. The dynamically loaded javascript executes perfectly. The problem comes when the the parent product also has a parent product. So if I press the **viewParentProduct** , it loads the same page (**product/view**) and inject it in the dom, duplicating the HTML elements and javascript.

Visually:

- **STAGE 1:** *Click on **viewProduct*** --> product/view/11 is injected into productInfo div

  - **STAGE 2:** *Click on **viewParentProduct*** --> product/view/15 is injected into parentProductInfo div

    - **STAGE 3:** *Click on **viewParentProduct*** --> product/view/{someOtherParentProductID} is injected into parentProductInfo div

At this point I am screwed. Since the same HTML/Javascript has been injected in the DOM twice, the next time I press on **viewParentProduct**, it'll trigger the wrong button and/or load the content of product/view in the wrong **parentProductInfo** div.

Of course I could do something like this but it's pretty ugly:

```
$(".viewProduct_11").on('click', .....

<button class="viewProduct_11" data-id="11">View Product</button>

<div id="productInfo_11"></div>

// Where 11 comes from PHP ex: <?php echo $productID; ?>
```

So my question is: **Is there a way to sort of "namespace" a set of javascript-HTML or do you know a way to fix this problem ?** Even if I namespaced the javascript, the HTML element's IDs would still be duplicated.

I'm really out of ideas!

**-----------------------EDIT-----------------------**

I need to have the javascript inside the view (product/view) because it's rather complex. In fact it has nothing to do with the simple snipped I used as an example in this question. I'd rather have the javascript related to the product/view page inside the view itself to improve cohesion. In reality, when clicking on the **viewProduct** button, the product/view page is loaded in a modal (a div with an overlay) and there can be multiple modal overlapping each other with **the same HTML/javascript code coming from product/view**. I could work around the javascript collision by wrapping the product/view's javascript in a namespace, however the HTML and the DOM elements and their ID will still be problematic. Hence why I'm looking for a way for namespacing a block of javascript AND HTML...somehow. I'm clueless.

Comment: I would consolidate all of that javascript to the parent page rather than having javascript included in dynamically generated html.

Comment: I agree with Kevin, have your javascript generic and in one spot.

Comment: Even f I did that, how would I map proper buttons to proper containers ? If I have one generic script that holds the $(".viewParentProduct").on('click' ..., how can I make sure the page will load in the container corresponding to this button.

Comment: I agree with the others, put your javascript in a .js file. Use classes, not Ids to avoid ID collisions, then use jQuery's `.on()` (replacing `.live()`) to attach event handlers, then use `.closest()` to find a parent of whichever button was pressed. You can use DOM traversal up and down so it's relative to whichever button was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("body").on('click', '.viewProduct', function() {
        var elem = $(this),
            productID = elem.data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://mywebappurl.com/product/view/" + productID,
            success: function(view) {
                elem.next().html(view);
            }
        });
});
</script>

<div class='viewWrapper'>
 <button class="viewProduct" data-id="11">View Product</button>

 <div class="productInfo"></div>
</div>
```

**product/view.php**

```
<div class='viewWrapper'>
 <button class="viewProduct" data-id="15">View Parent Product</button>

 <div class="productInfo"></div>
</div>

// Where 15 comes from PHP ex: <?php echo $productID; ?>
```

JavaScript from main page will be working for new loaded content.
ex.: http://jsfiddle.net/BV66Z/1/

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that doesn't really help me. I need to have my javascript within the view because the real Javascript i'm using for the product/view is much more complex than the simple snippet I used as an example in this question.